# WPF disable window moving

Tags: .net, wpf

In wpf how can i prevent user from moving the windows by dragging the title bar?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since you can't define a `WndProc` directly in WPF, you need to obtain a `HwndSource`, and add a hook to it :

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.SourceInitialized += Window1_SourceInitialized;
}

private void Window1_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
    source.AddHook(WndProc);    
}

const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam,  ref bool handled)
{

   switch(msg)
   {
      case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
          int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
          if (command == SC_MOVE)
          {
             handled = true;
          }
          break;
      default:
          break;
   }
   return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: What should WndProc return? IntPtr.Zero?

Comment: It's working, return value doesn't matter. So IntPrt.Zero is just fine.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the return value... According to the documentation of WM_SYSCOMMAND : "An application should return zero if it processes this message"

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks for posting it. One comment though, and that is that this makes the child window appear above EVERY other window on the machine. Is it possible to make it so that it's only above the parent?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel, this code merely prevents the window from being moved by the user. Perhaps your problem is caused by something else in your code...

Comment: Ah, stupid me! I was combining the code from two posts, and commented on the wrong one! Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks, this is working for .Net Framework 4.8, just don't forget to add the SourceInitialized event in the window you want to lock.

Answer (score 3):

Really old thread and other techniques like UWP and WinUI3 are out there but maybe my suggestions are helpful to others.

I achieve the goal by setting

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

Add a button to the window and set

```
IsCancel="True"
```

That's it. No need for interop code. Minimized code.

Comment: Why does this work? I don't get it.

Comment: because there is no visible space to put your mouse down to drag it. the window has no borders nor header.. job done.

Answer (score 0):

alt + space would still bring up the window context menu, giving you access to all commands. You would need to implement logic to override the default menu item behaviour to make this example work properly.

Comment: Regarding solution provided by Anzu, need 50 rep points to do inline comment.