# WPF behaves like Taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement at work for a WPF stock-ticker-like application. 
I was thinking of using this as a starting point: http://www.jarloo.com/rumormill4

But the one thing it does not do is dock to the top of the desktop window - AND - push down any other windows, maximized or otherwise. This app must *own* a small bit of vertical real estate at the top of the screen, full width. I scoured WPF posts, but cannot find an example. I've seen a third party solution, so I know it's possible. Window.Topmost almost achieves this behavior, but just covers/obscures anything under it. Any suggestions? 
The image below demonstrates the current behavior. The WPF window sits on top of VS, which is problem.

[image: Example of Visual studio obscured by toolbar]

Comment: Could you present the problem with screenshot (what you want) as well as post your attempted code/xaml? The link doesn't tell much about issue and we can't debug "words". What is "top" or "stock-ticker-like"? Custom taskbar?

Comment: Yes, my mistake was the search criteria. Reserving an area on the screen was what I am after. I think this will work. Many thanks

Comment: Google "wpf shappbarmessage" to find the code you need.  Top hit is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf) from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Set your XAML as the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Height" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hi there!" FontSize="36"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

We set `SizeToContent = Height` to achieve the height auto effect. `WindowState=Maximized` to achieve full width for the window.

Then in the codebehind use the following code to avoid that the user moves the window around:

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SourceInitialized += OnSourceInitialized;
            Left = 0;
            Top = 0;
        }

        private void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {

            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                    int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                    if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    {
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
```

I must say that I took the last part from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400888/4430204) by @Thomas Levesque.

The result is a nice top docked window with full width

Comment: This definitely stops the user from moving the window around. That's good, but it does not reserve it's area. So, another application, can be obscured by this window. I need any other window(outside of the WPF app) to honor the area's position and not fill the area underneath it.

Comment: Hi Michael K, 
I am trying to achieve something similar and was wondering if you found a solution to it. If yes, it would be much appreciated if you could share it with the community.

Thanks in advance:)